# How to do bit insertion

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, binary-operators

How to insert bits to a certain position?

For example, if I have an integer 115 (i.e. *b1110011*). 
And I want to insert integer 3 (i.e. *b11*) to position 3 from the right. In this case, let's assume that I know the size of the binary that I want to insert. For example, I know that 3 is 2 digits binary.

Therefore the resulting binary will be 475 (i.e. *b1110**11**011*)

I have a solution in mind but it seems complicated. It involves first, shifting the bits 2 digits to the left to give room for the new bits. Then set rightmost *2+position* bits to zero. Therefore now I have *1110**00000***. 

Then I will `OR` the result to change the bold bits part with the rightmost *2+position* from the original bits with the first two position is changed to the bits that I want to insert. (i.e. ***11**011*).

Therefore in the end I will have `111000000 | 11011 == 111011011`.

But I think my solution is too complicated. Thus, is there any better way to do this operation?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "set the rightmost *position+2* bits to zero"? That times two operation only worked by luck

Comment: ah you're right, edited

Comment: I don't think there is a better way though, unless you have some special instruction that is useful in this case.

Comment: PowerPC has some wonderful bit manipulation instructions, specifically [`rlwimi`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.alangref/idalangref_rlwimi_rlimi_rotwrd_instrs.htm), which can perform the above operation in one instruction.

Comment: If you are working with a modern CPU and have access to a low-level language, you might want to consider Intel's [Bit Manipulation Instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#BMI1_.28Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Set_1.29) Set I and II.